# In python is it possible to test if an object is an instance of a subclass of MyClass but not an instance of MyClass?

Tags: python, subclass, isinstance

I want to test if an object is an instance of a subclass but not an instance of the parent class. Example:

```
class MyClass():
  pass

class Sub1(MyClass):
  pass

class Sub2(MyClass):
  pass

obj = Sub1()
assert isinstance(obj, Sub1 | Sub2) and not isinstance(obj, MyClass)
```

Is there a test that scales for the case of many subclasses and is less cumbersome than `isinstance(obj, Sub1 | Sub2 | ... | SubN)`.

`issubclass(type(obj), MyClass)` is compact, but does not exclude objects that are instances of `MyClass` because [a class is considered a subclass of itself](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass).

Comment: Please update ypur snippet to be valid Python code.  Also, of course an object is an instance of its class' every superclass, by definition of class inheritance

Comment: You can probably monkey with the instance and “delete” its superclass if you bend over backwards far enough. However, then it also wouldn’t behave like the superclass, supposedly. Are you trying to conjure something like that on purpose, or are you wondering whether you need to worry about this scenario somehow?

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice then to check if `type(obj) is not MyClass`?